# Using a C++ class in C#

Tags: c#, c++

How can I use a C++ class in C#? I know you can use DllImport and have the class as IntPtr, but then how would I call the functions inside the class? And I don't want to create a new method for each method in the class and export that, then there is not point for me to use a class then...

**Without creating a COM app**

C++ Class:

```
class MyCPPClass 
{
public:
  MyCPPClass();
  ~MyCPPClass();
  void call_me();
}

extern "C" 
{
  extern __declspec(dllexport) MyCPPClass* __cdecl CreateClass() 
  {
    return new MyCPPClass();
  }
}
```

C#:

```
class MyCSClass
{
  [DllImport("MyCPPDll.dll")]
  static extern IntPtr CreateClass();

  public static void Main()
  {
    IntPtr cc = CreateClass();
    // Now I want to call cc->call_me();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're building your classes in C++/CLI, then you just just be able to use it as you would any regular .NET class.

If the DLL in question is accessible via COM, then use the COM interop to talk to it from .NET.

If OTOH you're looking at non-COM, plain vanilla C++, you will have to ensure that all classes and their members are exported...

My suggestion would be that if you want to use a plain vanilla C++ DLL, write a C++/CLI wrapper around it that can "talk .NET" to your C# code and "real C++" to the C++ DLL. You'll still have to export all the C++ classes and functions, but at least that way you're working in the same language before you transition to C#.

Answer (score 0):

To use c++ class, C++\CLI is a better option

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, C++ CLI is probably the easiest option.

The other standard option which you've started doing is to keep building on that C style facade you started and expose another method something like this:

```
extern "C" {  
    extern __declspec(dllexport) MyCPPClass* __cdecl CallMe(void* data)   
    {   
        MyCppClass* instance = (MyCppClass*) data;
        instance->call_me();
    }
}
```

then you can go through the tedium of creating a C# class that mirrors the functionality of your C++ class and hides the fact that the implementation is in another dll.

Or you could use C++ / CLI.